# Play Framework, RESTful API, and Media Type

Tags: rest, playframework

I'm implementing a RESTful API with Play... and even I would tend to support only JSON, it looks like it is good practice to also support XML. I've read some interesting articles on the Internet on how to design a good RESTful API and understood media type should be in the URL - the most used option seems to be appending the `.json` or `.xml` extension to the endpoint URL.

Now the question is: how do I implement this in Play? Shall I define a route for each format like this:

```
GET     /products.json/:id         controllers.Products.show(id: Int, format: String = "json")
GET     /products.xml/:id          controllers.Products.show(id: Int, format: String = "xml")
```

... or shall I define something like this:

```
GET     /products.:format/:id      controllers.Products.show(id: Int, format: String)
```

Personally, I would prefer specifying the media type in the `Accept header`... but it looks like this is discouraged or at least not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that both ways are pretty much accepted solutions for a REST API, so use the Accept header if you like that best!